# Angle between arc of two points on a unit sphere and $xy$-plane

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spheres

Suppose I have two points on a unit sphere whose spherical coordinates are $A(\theta_1,\phi_1)$ and $B(\theta_2,\phi_2)$, what is the angle between $xy$-plane and arc $AB$?

Maybe I can draw a triangle with the north pole and use cosine rule, but I couldn't figure out how.

Edit: For my application, the angle I need is the minmum angle between the tangent 
of any point on the arc and $xy$-plane.

Comment: What do you mean by the angle between an arc and a plane?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear, for my application I need to make sure at any point of the arc, the slope is bigger than 60°, so I think I will need the minmum slope of the arc.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to explain "the slope (at a point $P$)"? Particularly, do you mean (i) the azimuth of the ray from the origin through $P$; (ii) The azimuth of the line through $P$ and tangent to the arc $AB$; (iii) something else? (Separately, you'll need to specify what convention you're using for spherical coordinates; there are at least four in fairly wide use, and they're mutually incompatible.) Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf{a}=
(\sin \theta_{1} \cos \phi_{1},\sin \theta_{1} \sin \phi_{1},\cos  \phi_{1})$ and $\mathbf{b}=(\sin \theta_{2} \cos \phi_{2},\sin \theta_{2} \sin \phi_{2},\cos  \phi_{2})$

The required angle is
$$\cos^{-1}
\left(
  \frac{\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{k}}
       {|\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}|}
\right)$$

The computation of $\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{k}$ is easy but 
$|\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}|$ is awful unless $\theta_{1}=\theta_{2}$ or $\phi_{1}=\phi_{2}$.